# Error Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX 10.10 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos

I cannot get ruby 1.9.3 to install on the new Yosemite operating system. When trying to install I get the following error.

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p547
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p547.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/9ba118e4aba04c430bc4d5efb09b31a0277e101c9fd2ef3b80b9c684d7ae57a1
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p547...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/1s/ct5g_n2s5l7c0z8jm2f39gp00000gn/T/ruby-build.20140605114326.32968
Results logged to /var/folders/1s/ct5g_n2s5l7c0z8jm2f39gp00000gn/T/ruby-build.20140605114326.32968.log

Last 10 log lines:
    0 enumerator.so

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

make: *** [encdb.h] Abort trap: 6
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Has anyone run into this yet?

Comment: I have — sadly, I wish I had a fix as well. Happens if I try installing `1.9.3-p327`.

Comment: Happened to me with `2.1.3`. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309860/unable-to-build-ruby-2-1-3-on-osx-10-10-gm-3-0-with-rbenv/26503655#26503655