# Unable to build Ruby 2.1.3 on OSX 10.10 GM 3.0 with rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos

I have found several threads where other users have had similar issues but none of them are seem to be like this.

After issuing the command:

```
rbenv install 2.1.3
```

I get the following errors:

```
Installing ruby-2.1.3...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.10 using ruby-build 20140926)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/y_/5mjltxsn35q0n_k5817bszlw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20141010202255.63586
Results logged to /var/folders/y_/5mjltxsn35q0n_k5817bszlw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20141010202255.63586.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for cd using physical directory... cd -P
checking whether CFLAGS is valid... no
configure: error: something wrong with CFLAGS=" -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  "
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/610), have you tried this?  `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--without-gcc --disable-install-rdoc" rbenv install 2.1.3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Homebrew package for gcc on Yosemite [seems to be broken](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/610#issuecomment-55773864). That's why it doesn't work.

Had the same issue. Running:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 2.1.3
```

worked for me.

Comment: The home-brew package appears to be fixed. `brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build` should now sort it :)

Comment: My issue with `config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists` was solved with this, after so many other attempts. Fantastic!!!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in ruby-build for rbenv. Please update by the following:

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/
git pull
```

Comment: Thank you, I remembered that I had done that in the past and it worked.

Comment: I think this assumes you didn't install `rbenv` through `homebrew`. My `plugins` dir has no `ruby-build` dir.