# Inspect or clean up the working tree when installing Ruby on Mac M1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, ruby-build

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.5.1 by running `rbenv install 2.5.1` and keep getting the below failure:

```
BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.0.1 using ruby-build 20211203)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_n/7rd4p8r578db_ct2rrwhvwv80000gn/T/ruby-build.20211204124341.35704.JFosKp
Results logged to /var/folders/_n/7rd4p8r578db_ct2rrwhvwv80000gn/T/ruby-build.20211204124341.35704.log

Last 10 log lines:
    rb_mObjSpace = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("ObjectSpace"));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1755:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
```

Tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568713/inspect-or-clean-up-the-working-tree-error-when-installing-ruby-2-1-3-on-mac-os) and [here](https://rubyflow.com/p/g61v9t-fix-build-failed-while-installing-ruby-with-rbenv-on-m1-mac).

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by running `$ RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.5.1`

Comment: I ran that command, and it says... `No versions specified for 2.5.1 in config files or environment` — any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: As of today: `RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.8` still fails. crap

Answer (score 0):

RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.5.9
its working fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).